# ¿Por qué no funciona este bucle while?

Tags: c++

Estoy empezando a programar desde hace pocos días en C++, la transición desde Python me está costando un poco. Intento crear un programa que calcule todos los números perfectos entre 1 y 1000 considerando que el 1 no es un número perfecto, y he creado este código, no sé muy bien dónde está el error, pego el código que he escrito (no se imprime nada por pantalla).

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int i,j,sum;
    i = 2;
    while (i<=1000)
    {
        j = 1;
        sum = 0;
        while (j<i)
        {
            if (i%j == 0)
            {
                sum = sum + j;
                j+=1;
            }
            i+=1;
        }
        if (sum == i)
            cout << i << "es un número perfecto";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Gracias de antemano, le he dado muchas vueltas y no sé muy bien donde falla.

Comment: Estás atorado en los LOOPS. Mira... https://i.gyazo.com/370c16b7775b2417b1712872fe394bb1.mp4

Comment: Y si algo no funciona, deberias al menos ir imprimiendo los valores por pantalla, por que es la única forma visual de ver que ocurre, en este caso, nunca estás saliendo de los whiles.

Answer (score 2):

El problema esta dentro del segundo ciclo while:

```
int main()
{
    ...
    while (i<=1000)
    {
        ...
        while (j<i)
        {
            if (i%j == 0)
            {
                sum = sum + j;
                j+=1;
            }
            i+=1;
        }
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

tiene un ciclo if con la comparaction de i % j == 0, donde si es verdad se hace la operacion de suma e incrementa el valor de j. despues de ese ciclo if incrementa el valor de i. El error esta en que esa comparacion del ciclo if rara vez es verdadera por lo que no se incrementa el valor de j a la par con i o mas, mientras que en cada iteracion del segundo cliclo while se sigue incrementando el valor de i, y como no se cumple el condicion de ese ciclo while ya que siempre j es menor que i, no puede salir, por lo que basicamente es un loop infinito.

La solucion que yo recomiendo es mover el incremento de i al primer ciclo while, debajo del segundo, y mover el incremento de j fuera del ciclo if y pasarlo al final del while, por ejemplo:

```
while (i<=1000)
{
    j = 1;
    sum = 0;
    while (j<i)
    {
        if (i%j == 0)
        {
            sum = sum + j;
        }
        j+=1;
    }
    i+=1;
    ...
}
```